# Keycloack for native /desktop application in c# REST APIs, not working properly or am I missing something?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, native, openid-connect, keycloak-rest-api

I can get the authorization code and access token by a keycloak endpoint ONLY when I already have the browser opened and already did the login, otherwise the code fails to get the authorization code.

so considering I implement this logic at the application start ( it's not definitive ) , I have to run it 2 times to get code and then the token.

I just use rest APIs because I can not find an understandable keycloak library to use for desktop / native applications.

this is my code:

```
public static async  Task<string>  GetTokenAsync()
    {
 
        string redirectURI = string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/", "localhost", GetRandomUnusedPort());
        string RedirectURIWithoutLastSlash = redirectURI.TrimEnd('/');
 
 
        string code = await GetCodeForAuthentication(redirectURI, RedirectURIWithoutLastSlash);
 
        UnityWebRequest request = new UnityWebRequest();
        request.url = $"https://tokenEndpoint.../protocol/openid-connect/token";
 
        request.method = UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbPOST;
        request.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
       
 
 
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 
        string postData = "";
 
        Dictionary<string, string> postParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>() /
            {
                {"grant_type", "authorization_code"},
                {"code", code},
                {"client_id", "myID"},
                {"client_secret", "mySECRET"},
                {"redirect_uri", RedirectURIWithoutLastSlash }
            };
 
        foreach (string key in postParameters.Keys)
            postData += UnityWebRequest.EscapeURL(key) + "=" + UnityWebRequest.EscapeURL(postParameters[key]) + "&";
 
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
 
        request.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(data) ;
 
        request.timeout = 60;
 
        request.SendWebRequest();
 
        while (!request.isDone)
        {
            Debug.Log(request.downloadProgress);
        }
 
        Debug.Log("text by server is: " + request.downloadHandler.text);
 
        TokenClass token = JsonUtility.FromJson<TokenClass>(request.downloadHandler.text);
 
        access_token = token.access_token;
 
        tokenInfo = token;
        Debug.Log("access token is: " + access_token);
 
        return access_token;
    }
 
    private static async Task<string> GetCodeForAuthentication(string redirectURI, string RedirectURIWithoutLastSlash)
    {
 
     
 
        string code = null;
 
        HttpListener http = new HttpListener();
        http.Prefixes.Add(redirectURI);
        http.Start();
 
 
 
        string authorizationRequest = $"https://authCode Endpoint.../protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=myID&response_type=code&response_mode=query&scope=profile&redirect_uri={RedirectURIWithoutLastSlash}";
 
        // Opens request in the browser.
        Process web_Login_Process = new Process();
        web_Login_Process.StartInfo.FileName = GetSystemDefaultBrowser();
        web_Login_Process.StartInfo.Arguments = authorizationRequest;
        web_Login_Process.Start();
 
 
            try
            {
             
                var context = await http.GetContextAsync();
                var response = context.Response;
 
                var html = "<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='10;url=https://localhost'></head><body>Please return to the Digital Twin.</body></html>";
 
 
                string responseString = string.Format(html);
                var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
                response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
                var responseOutput = response.OutputStream;
                Task responseTask = responseOutput.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ContinueWith((task) =>
                {
                    responseOutput.Close();
                    http.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine("HTTP server stopped.");
                });
           
           
            // Checks for errors.
            if (context.Request.QueryString.Get("error") != null)
                {
                    string debug = context.Request.QueryString.Get("error");
 
                }
                if (context.Request.QueryString.Get("code") == null
                    || context.Request.QueryString.Get("state") == null)
                {
 
                    var debug = context.Request.QueryString; //no keys, Lenght is equal to 0
 
                    var debug3 = context.Request.RawUrl; // favicon.ico is the result
 
 
                }
                // extracts the code
                code = context.Request.QueryString.Get("code");
 
                string tryCode = context.Request.QueryString["code"];
 
                Debug.Log("code is: " + code);
 
               
 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string g = ex.Message;
            }
 
        return code;
    }
```

any help on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [C# Sample](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/main/ConsoleSystemBrowser) that you can follow for the desktop flow and borrow some ideas from. Note that the OAuth flow for console apps is the same as for desktop apps.

You should be using PKCE for the desktop app security and the above library will implement this for you

For something to compare against with the correct OAuth behaviour, see these resources of mine:

- [Desktop code sample you can run](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample1)
- [Desktop blog posts](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/17/desktop-app-how-to-run-the-code-sample/)

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, I am trying to run the C# Sample you sent me, I managed to change the OIDCClientOptions to communicate with the server, but I am facing an issue, the line of code "var response = await callbackManager.RunServer();".

Comment: "var response = await callbackManager.RunServer();" - this line of code hangs the application!, I also noticed that in the OidcCLientOptions it is not possible to set the information "response_mode" to "code" .

Comment: Hmm - I've not run the sample myself, but I'm aware it exists and uses the standards based approach. Sounds like you can at least use it as a guide: spin up the HTTP server in a child thread perhaps. In terms of OAuth forlds: response_type should be code and response_mode should be query - I think the library will do that for you.

Comment: Yes of course I can use it as a guide,  and thank you very much for that! the problem I am facing is that responseMode is not settable to "code", if  I do not set that field, it will be FormPost. so weird